# Pushing changes to root folder rather than var

Tags: git, bitbucket, digital-ocean

I have two directories of the website project, one is in the var/www/my_webfiles, and the other one, copy of the same directory files is in root/www/my_webfiles. The files that gets published on the server are in the root folder while the file that BitBucket updates is in the var directory.
Any suggestions you may have will be very much appreciated, I'm thinking what I have to do is set things so that BitBucket updates the files in the root folder rather than the var ones its been updating (hence why the changes I made and pushed aren't showing on the server). Any suggestion on how to set things up so that BitBucket pushes updates to the directory in the root folder ?

Comment: To solve what you asked, just checkout the Bitbucket code to the root folder. But keep in mind that you should NEVER USE ROOT like this! You are potentially opening security holes all over the place! Run the website out of the place it should run -- /var/www/.....

Comment: @mrunion - Thanks! What I really want is to have the site/server feed off the files from the var directory rather than the root that its currently using. Any suggestions on how I can switch things to working that way?

Comment: If you want to serve the files from /var/www/.... but NOT have the entire bitbucket repo there, there are multiple approaches. The simplest may be to just use rsync and ignore the .git folder. You can always use git itself but only retrieve the code one commit deep. Is that what you mean?